# Google Places Autocomplete API crashed on some phones

Tags: android, android-studio, search, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to implement Google Places Autocomplete API, but the search bar for it crashed on some phones every time when I search for something.

It does work on some phones (like Moto G 2nd Generation XT1068) but crashes on Lenovo A7000 whenever I search anything in the search bar and then press enter.

Another problem I face is; I want to change the default google maps location that shows near South Africa. Change it to a specific location. How can I do that?

```
package com.docto365.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


import com.docto365.R;

public class HospitalMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity /*implements OnMapReadyCallback*/ implements LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager location;
    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    private static final LatLngBounds Bhubaneswar = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(20.192597, 85.792239), new LatLng(20.409371, 85.824544));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospital_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        /*SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);*/
        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setHint("Search Hospitals & Clinics");
        autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(Bhubaneswar);
        mActionBarToolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mActionBarToolbar.setTitle("     Hospitals & Clinics");
        mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
        mActionBarToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mActionBarToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        location= (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1000, this);



        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                //Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
                //Toast.makeText(HospitalMapsActivity.this, "Place: " + place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autotext);
                //String destination = et.getText().toString();
                String destination = (String) place.getName();

                List<Address> addressList = null;
                if (destination == null || !destination.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HospitalMapsActivity.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(destination, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(destination));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                //Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
                Toast.makeText(HospitalMapsActivity.this, "An error occured: " + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        //setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }



    private void setUpMapIfNeeded()
    {
        if(mMap==null)
            mMap=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if(mMap!=null)
            setUpMap();
    }
    private void setUpMap()
    {
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(20.271790,85.843858)).title("Marker").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 17.0f ) );
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(HospitalMapsActivity.this,"Tap on healthcare centre name to book a cab",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HospitalMapsActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Book Cab");
                dialog.setMessage("Do you want to book a cab?"/*HospitalMapsActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled)*/);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Book now"/*HospitalMapsActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings)*/, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(HospitalMapsActivity.this, Book.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        //get gps
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Later"/*HospitalMapsActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings)*/, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //get gps
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)HospitalMapsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;

        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(HospitalMapsActivity.this,"Something is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(HospitalMapsActivity.this,"Something is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(gps_enabled==false /*&& network_enabled==false*/) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HospitalMapsActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Location Services Disabled");
            dialog.setMessage("Please enable location services."/*HospitalMapsActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled)*/);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Enable"/*HospitalMapsActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings)*/, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    HospitalMapsActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    //get gps
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }



        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(20.260423, 85.777747)).title("AMRI HOSPITALS").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sp)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15.0f);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        location.removeUpdates(this);






                    setUpMapIfNeeded();
        //mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(20.269556,85.841157) , 14.0f) );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack overflow. Please post one question at time. Try to gather here the most informations you can about your errors (what are the OS version of these phones i.e. ?)

Comment: Lenovo a7000 has v4.4.4 and the search bar in this phone lets the app to stop. Moto G2nd generation has v6.0.1 but here everything works fine.

Comment: Are you able to add a stack trace of the crash? That might help people work out what's going wrong. Looking at onPlaceSelected() I see that addressList can be accessed before being set (if geocoder.getFromLocationName() throws an exception). Maybe this is what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your problems:

**It does work on some phones (like Moto G 2nd Generation XT1068) but crashes on Lenovo A7000 whenever I search anything in the search bar and then press enter.**

Please check the following:

- Check if your Android platform is included in supported versions given in [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html).
- As mentioned in Google Places API - [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#troubleshooting), majority of the errors that your app is likely to experience are usually caused by configurations error. To get the status message for the errors that occur , call `PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus()` in `onActivityResult()` callback.
- In using Place Autocomplete, please check if autocomplete is properly added to your app, as given in [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete), using the following ways:

  - Add an autocomplete widget
  - Get place predictions programmatically

You may also check the given workaround in this GitHub post - [Google Places Autocomplete does not work on mobile](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1798) wherein a relevant code was placed into a function and then used the `ng-focus` directive to execute the expression on the desired element like:

```
<input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-focus="disableTap()">
```

**Another problem I face is; I want to change the default google maps location that shows near South Africa. Change it to a specific location. How can I do that?**

- To change default google maps location and to get precise results, try given steps in  [Update your location on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1) wherein you can:

  - Turn your location on or off, and
  - Check and update your location

For more information, please try going through the given documentations.

I hope one works for you.